# Would it be possible to have a schedule apperance of image link in you website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just want to create a scheduled appearance of icon/images or PDF  on my website,
for example I need to flash on the upper right header of my website the day today: ea MONDAY and it will change if the day change as well,

How could I code that?

Comment: Please post your code. We're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a switch statement to activate certain HTML elements based on the day of the week

```
switch((new Date()).getDay()) {
  case 0:
    // Sunday
    unhide('sun');
    break;
  case 1:
    // Monday
    unhide('mon');
    break;
  case 2:
    // Tuesday
    unhide('tues');
    break;
  case 3:
    // Wednesday
    unhide('wed');
    break;
  case 4:
    // Thursday
    unhide('thurs');
    break;
  case 5:
    // Friday
    unhide('fri');
    break;
  case 6:
    // Saturday
    unhide('sat');
    break;
}
```

And your unhide function could look something like this

```
function unhide(id) {
   var element = document.getElementById(id);
   element.className = element.className.replace('hidden', '');
}
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/g671t71a/

Comment: Thanks Preston, this help me so much to finish my first project on this field.